# PHPUnit error - Can't run Laravel tests from Command line using MAMP Server

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I've been having this issue for quite some time now. First of all, I have MAMP Pro Server installed on my Mac OS and the default PHP Version selected is 7.3.8. I have also checked the 'Make this version available on the command line' option. But whenever I try to run laravel tests using the `phpunit` command, I get the following error;

```
PHPUnit 8.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

This version of PHPUnit is supported on PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3, and PHP 7.4.
You are using PHP 7.1.16 (/usr/bin/php).
```

I have confirmed my php version on available on the command line using `php -v` an it outputs

```
PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 14 2019 16:42:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.8, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Please kindly help.

Comment: What does ```/usr/bin/php -v``` give you? Hint: php may not be linked to /usr/bin/php. Check it with ```whereis php``` in the command line

Comment: ```/usr/bin/php -v``` gives me ```PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2018 02:59:59) ( NTS )``` and also ```whereis php``` gives me ```/usr/bin/php```

Comment: Okay, that seems to be the right step to go forward on: Your "/usr/bin/php" links to the wrong php version. Can you execute ```php -r 'echo PHP_BINDIR;'``` to see where your php alias is located at?

Comment: Thanks. I've just done that, and it links to ```/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/bin```

Comment: I've provided an answer that should fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your /usr/bin/php file does not link to your MAMPs version of php. This file is used by phpunit (in your case).

Let me tell you how you can **switch it**:

First of all, move away the original link

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.bak
```

Then link /usr/bin/php to your actual MAMP PHP version:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/bin /usr/bin/php
```

Validate it with `/usr/bin/php -v` giving you the 7.3.8 version.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an operation not permitted error in each case. Do I need to turn off my server before trying out the commands?

Comment: You have to run it with an account that has permission to change system settings

Comment: Does the following help you further with this? http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/